# How to override a material-ui-next css in React?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How to override a material-ui-next css in React?

ex:

```
.MuiListItem-button-119 {
  transition: background-color 150ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
}
```

How to change globally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
        MuiList:{
            padding:{
                paddingTop:0,
                paddingBottom:0
            }
        },
        MuiListItem: {
            button: {
                '&:hover': {
                    backgroundColor: 'rgb(0,0,0,0)'
                },
            },
        },
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if it will work with your case, but usually u should use !important in css

`elm{ 
prop:val !important;
}`